# PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver but shut it down after new session created

Tags: eclipse, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

hi i am getting following error while launching phantomjs in eclipse for java
PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver...
[image]

i have done following steps to add phantomjs to eclipse :

1. Download phantomjs.exe
2. Extract the phantomjs-1.8.x-windows.zip folder and locate phantomjs.exe file to C:/ folder
3. Add the following imports to your code:

### import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver; import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService; import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

Replace the object, "driver" specifying "FirefoxDriver" with "PhantomJSDriver".

Replace the code,
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver

DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true); 
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "C:/phantomjs.exe");
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);

Run Test.

please help !!

Answer (score 2):

in order to make GhostDriver work properly following steps below:

```
                      PREREQUISITES
```

prerequisite step 1:

- [download selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/). For example purposes I place it in C:\Selenim folder
- [download phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/download). Place it in C:\Selenim folder as well

After everything you need is downloaded, next step - is to launch  selenium hub (selenium server )  and selenium node that will be connected to the  launched hub and will be based on phantomJs.

```
                   LAUNCHING HUB AND NODES
```

1. selenium hub start

   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role hub

After you launched hub - check it locally  typing `http://localhost:4444/grid/console`  in browser  => 
http://gyazo.com/9435772d76044cf273d6b567584c0532

1. GhostDriver node launch

   phantomjs  --webdriver=8080 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http:// l o c a l h o s t:4444

check again localhost/grid/console => http://gyazo.com/06fd2fc6d740c18e3d0925e180de150f

After you've done with that, make the following setUp.

```
                               CODE SETUP
```

**Approach One**

My project- is maven based, so I would recommend you following PhantomJs crossplatform solution

In POM.XML add the following

```
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
             <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
             <version>2.41.0</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
             <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
             <version>2.41.0</version>
         </dependency>


<!--substituting   phanbedder  with local Phanbedder implementation-->
             <dependency>
         <groupId>net.anthavio</groupId>
         <artifactId>phanbedder-1.9.7</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
     </dependency>



     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
         <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.0</version>
     </dependency>
```

after adding these dependencies,  switch to test class (e.g. SeleniumTest.java)

```
 private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void seleniumGrridUponGhostDriver() throws MalformedURLException {


       File phantomjs = Phanbedder.unpack(); // cross platform solution. Maven will provide //appropriate phantomJs instance

        DesiredCapabilities dcaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dcaps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);


        dcaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, phantomjs.getAbsolutePath());

// NOTE: as we launched node locally, that is why we pass
// 127.0.0.1  IP as parameter
        this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080"), dcaps);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

@Test
public void myTest(){
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
.....

}
```

**Approach Two**

add following depencies in POM.xml

```
    <dependency>
             <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
             <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
             <version>2.41.0</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
             <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
             <version>2.41.0</version>
         </dependency>
```

appropriate code setUP:

```
  private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void seleniumGrridUponGhostDriver() throws MalformedURLException {

        File phantomjs = new File("C:\\Selenium\\phantomjs.exe");


        DesiredCapabilities dcaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dcaps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);


        dcaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, phantomjs.getAbsolutePath());

        this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080"), dcaps);


        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    }

    @Test
    public void myTest(){
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    .....

    }
```

Hope this works for you